# Impossible to disable return value optimization for std::string?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, return-value-optimization

Given this minimal example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_ptr(const std::string& s)
{
    const char* data = s.data();
    std::cout << "ptr: " << (void*)data << std::endl;
}

std::string str_return(const char* suffix)
{
    std::string s("prefix");
    s += " ";
    s += suffix;
    print_ptr(s);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = str_return("suffix"), t;
    print_ptr(s);
    t = str_return("suffix2");
    print_ptr(t);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled like this:

```
g++ -std=c++98 -fno-elide-constructors -g -Wall  str_return.cpp -o str_return
```

My g++:

```
gcc version 4.7.1
```

The output:

```
ptr: 0x804b04c
ptr: 0x804b04c
ptr: 0x804b07c
ptr: 0x804b07c
```

Why are the pointers still equal?

- It should not be return value optimization - I switched it off
- It should not be move constructors since I took a really old standard of c++

How can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: Is there any reason to do that?

Comment: @JurajBlaho I just want to be sure what's the reason for it's not a copy. That way, I know what is necessary for a fast string return.

Comment: Just FYI: when compiled using clang (3.2) with the gcc libstdc++, I get a segmentation fault upon the return from `str_return()`. **This strongly hints at a bug/non-standard behaviour of the library**. When using the llvm libc++, the pointers are different (though it reuses `s.data()` in `t`, i.e. the 1st and 3rd line report the same ptr).

Comment: @Walter, that means your clang installation is borked, not that there's a bug in libstdc++. libstdc++ uses Copy-On-Write for its `std::string` which is 100% conforming in C++03 (which this example uses)

Comment: If you want to prevent Copy-On-Write sharing of the buffer copy the buffer explicitly: `std::string copy(s.data(), s.size())`, but in this example that's just a harmful pessimisation, because after `str_return` returns `s` and `t` are not sharing their data with another object anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return value optimization affects the local object (`s` in your `str_return` function). You never instrument that.

The string object itself manages dynamic memory and chooses to hand that managed memory over to the next string upon return. What you're instrumenting is *that* managed memory. Sensibly enough, that doesn't change.

If you really want to see the effect of RVO, instrument the local object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_ptr(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << "ptr: " << static_cast<const void *>(&s) << std::endl;
}

std::string str_return(const char* suffix)
{
    std::string s("prefix");
    s += " ";
    s += suffix;
    print_ptr(s);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = str_return("suffix");
    print_ptr(s);
    std::string t = str_return("suffix2");
    print_ptr(t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get what you mean from the example. So you think that there is nothing that will make my compiler do a hard copy of the *internal* data?

Comment: @Johannes: You can force a copy of the object if you like.

Comment: Ok, but this code, unchanged, will probably always be safe of hard copies (no matter what compiler flags I'll use)?

Comment: @Johannes: It will in C++11. It's unspecified in C++98/03.

Comment: What does _"be safe of hard copies"_ mean?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be experiencing RVO. The observed behavior may be caused by the copy on write optimization used in the implementation of `std::string` in GCC. Therefore a copy constructor may actually run, but the allocated buffer is not copied.

Comment: It's not "non-standard" in C++98, and in C++11 there are move semantics which produce the same behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB See my comment to the original Q.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment answers, so I will put my notice here:
If you put constructor call for you string s, and after that you call str_return - addresses will be different:

```
std::string s; // implicit constructor call
print_ptr( s );
s  = str_return( "suffix" );
print_ptr( s );
std::cout << std::endl;
```

the output will be:

```
ptr: 0x28fec4  // for the original s;
ptr: 0x28fec8  // for local variable in function str_return
ptr: 0x28fec4  // the address of s after call str_return didn't change
```

Comment: That isn't helpful, the objects don't contain the same data in your example.

Comment: Didn't get you. Which objects have to contain the same data?

Comment: The default constructed string doesn't contain the same data as the one returned by `str_return`. In any case, you apparently didn't test with GCC or another implementation that use COW strings, because the address of the string held by `s` **does** change if you use COW strings.  All you've done is show that another implementation behaves differently to GCC, which doesn't help the OP who is using GCC.

Comment: After assigning s = str_return( "suffix" ); s will be "prefix suffix". And it was compiled by g++. And if you look closer, after assigning the result of the function str_return to the string s, its address still same: 0x28fec4, like after calling constructor.

Comment: What are you printing out, the address of the string object, or its data?  Because with G++ the data will change after assignment.